Integrating "Facebook login for business" in web portal
While Integrating the Facebook login for business I am facing "It looks like this app isen't available".
I have followed all the steps mention in the META documentation.
please click here to refer the images which I have followed.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value='/facebooksdk/js/fbsdk.js'/>"></script>
    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            appId      : APPID,
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true,
            version    : APIVERSION,
            response_type: "code"
          });
          checkLoginState();
        };
        (function(d, s, id){
           var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
           if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
           js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
           js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
           fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
         }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
      </script>
</head>

<body>  
    <fb:login-button onlogin="checkLoginState();"> </fb:login-button>
    <div id="status">
    </div>
</body>
</html>

const APPID = "1450727115804587";
const APIVERSION = "v19.0";
const CONFIGID = "422168783777066";

function statusChangeCallback(response) { // Called with the results from FB.getLoginStatus().
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response); // The current login status of the person.
    if (response.status === 'connected') { // Logged into your webpage and Facebook.
        testAPI();
    } else { // Not logged into your webpage or we are unable to tell.
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log '
            + 'into this webpage.';
    }
}

function checkLoginState() { // Called when a person is finished with the Login Button.
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) { // See the onlogin handler
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
}

function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function (response) {
        console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Thanks for logging in, '
            + response.name + '!';
    });
}

Step 1 : Create a new app
Note : I have selected Other option
Select an App Type  -> I have  selected an second option Business App Type
Provide App Name & Business Profile and click on Create App
(3.1) Business App details
- Business app is verified
App Details :
- Display Name - EduCRM
-  App Domain : educloud.app
-  Privacy policy & Terms of service Url : https://zdp2.educloud.app/lms/tandc
- Category : Education
- Image Update : Yes
Add Product “facebook login for business”
Click Setup button of Facebook Login for Business

Vali Oatuh Redirect url - https://zur1.educloud.app/webhooks/fblogincallback/
Trun on Javascript SDK option
Allowed Domains for the JavaScript SDK : https://zur1.educloud.app

Facebook Login for business get Advance permission
Permission requested
pages_show_list
ads_management
leads_retrieval
pages_read_engagement
pages_manage_metadata
pages_read_user_content
pages_manage_ads
pages_manage_engagement
public_profile
Configuration
Quick Start steps:
Select Web option : to get SDK code
Make the App live :
